# How to measure Touch Pressure in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

As the title says, is there a method in **libGDX** which returns the touch pressure (similar to MotionEvent.getPressure() in Android) ?

Or is there any other way I can get touch pressure in my game which works on both android and iOS(using RoboVM)?

Comment: I don't think this is supported yet in libgdx. And I don't think iOS devices have this feature yet.

Comment: You will probably have to go with (android) platform specific code here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the iOS part
but for android there is a work around

you can do something like this to get the pressure

```
View view = initializeForView(game, config);
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        getInput().onTouch(v, event);
        game.setPressure(event.getPressure());
        Log.v("log", "hooked " + event.getPressure());
        return true;
    }
});
```

and still have the complete event handling of libgdx